# Cleaning our survey data, stuck. The first questions turned into 4 variables, each with a 1-0 response

Tags: r, data-cleaning, survey

I need to combine a set of survey responses(outputs) in R into 1 variable that has multiple factor responses.  In the outputs below, `$Q1-1` through `$Q1-5` should be combined into a Factor w/ 5 levels, with `Aid = 1`, `Assistant = 2`, `Owner = 3`, `Lead = 4`, `other = 5`.

BUT `Q1_5` through `Q1-_5` through Q1_5_6 are also part of the same 5 factor output. A respondent who selects 5 (other) has the option to write in an answer.

From what I read online I think maybe my issue is due to the data including both logic and factor responses to the same question but, honestly I just don't know what is even causing this error. I can't find anything similar online.

Any suggestions on how to combine the separate Factor 1 level responses while keeping them linked to the `Q1_5` responses?

The total output is huge, so I'm including just a small section of it below so you can see what I'm trying to explain. I'm filling an empty role on my research team, cleaning up our data for analysis, which means I am learning R as I go. Apologies if I am missing something obvious. Any advice/help/suggestions appreciated!

```
str(mydatafromR)>
'data.frame':   24 obs. of  456 variables:
 $ ResponseId  : Factor w/ 24 levels 
 ",..: 8 7 15 13 19 20 6 10 16 12 ...
 $ Q1_1        : Factor w/ 1 level "Lead": 1 NA NA 1 1 
1 1 NA NA NA ...
 $ Q1_2        : Factor w/ 1 level "Owner": NA NA 1 1 NA NA 
 NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Q1_3        : Factor w/ 1 level "Assistant": NA NA NA NA 
NA NA NA 1 1 1 ...
 $ Q1_4        : Factor w/ 1 level "Aid": NA 1 NA NA NA NA 
NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Q1_5        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Q1_5_TEXT   : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Q1_5_0      : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Q1_5_1      : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Q1_5_2      : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Q1_5_3      : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Q1_5_4      : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Q1_5_5      : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Q1_5_6      : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Comment: I forgot to add: The closest I got to keeping the data assigned to the correct cases was using:   
    sapply(mydatafromR, as.integer)        I cant figure out how to show the output here. But it kept the data assigned to the correct cases, but the responses were still split into 4 groups.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data using dput(head(mydatafromR)) -- it's hard to reproduce the problem using the str() data.

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like you data conforms with your description. Row 4 has a 1 for both lead and owner.